# printbibliography with defernumber=true results [0]

Tags: biblatex

I try to list all the publications into Chapters, Articles, and Conference proceeding using `\printbibliography`

```
\nocite{*}
% \printbibheading[title={Book Chapters}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=inbook,title= {Book Chapters},resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=article,title={Journal Articles},resetnumbers=true]
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,type=inproceedings,title={Conference Proceedings},resetnumbers=true]
```

With the `defernumbers=true`:
[image]
With the `defernumbers=false`:
[image]

I am looking for a way to have the reference starting from 1 at each section (book chapters 1-5, articles  1-...).
Thanks so much for reading the post.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Questions like this are extremely hard (almost impossible) to answer if we only get to see part of the code in screenshots. We need to see a fully compilable example document that reproduces the output with as little code as possible (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Coming up with such an example document takes some time and effort and it is not unlikely that you discover the solution while creating one. In its current form the question cannot be answered properly by anyone other than you and question and answer are unlikely to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I found the answer, it is because the .bbl cannot compile correctly due to other miss cites. I check and remove the wrong cite and recompile the bbl and the whole folder work. [image]

Now I want to sort the publication from newest to oldest in descending order.
For example Book Chapter : 5->1 (year from 2020-older)
Does anyone knows have any other recommendations? So lonely

Comment: Please keep in mind that TeX.SX is a Q&A site and not a normal, linear forum. Amongst other things that means that there is a strict separation between questions, answers and comments. The space here is reserved for answers to your question on top only. As such the first half of this post is perfectly fine, but the second bit (the follow-up question) should be asked as a new question. That helps keep the site clean and its contents relevant for all visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Found quite lengthy solution for this:

```
\AtDataInput[inbook]{%
 \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
  \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \csnumgdef{bookentrycount:\therefsection}{%
      \csuse{bookentrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{labelnumber}{\mkbibbookdesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibbookdesc}[1]{%
\number\numexpr\csuse{bookentrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}

\AtDataInput[article]{%
 \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
  \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \csnumgdef{articleentrycount:\therefsection}{%
      \csuse{articleentrycount:\therefsection}+1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{labelnumber}{\mkbibarticledesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibarticledesc}[1]{%
 \number\numexpr\csuse{articleentrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}


\AtDataInput[inproceedings]{%
 \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{entrylist:\therefsection}{}{%
  \listcsxadd{entrylist:\therefsection}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
  \csnumgdef{inproceedingscount:\therefsection}{%
      \csuse{inproceedingscount:\therefsection}+1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{labelnumber}{\mkbibinproceedingscountdesc{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibinproceedingscountdesc}[1]{%
 \number\numexpr\csuse{inproceedingscount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}
```